# jquery multiselect: How to get value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I use the jQuery [multiSelect](http://loudev.com/) plugin, but I have no idea how to collect the selected value on the right side and send to database.
My afterselect does not work.

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="add-group-select" name="my-select[]">
</select>
```

**jQUery**

```
$('#myModal_add_new_group').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'users',
        async : true,
        success : function(datas) {
                //console.log(datas);
                stringa ="";
                for(var i in datas){
                    var data = datas[i];                        
                    stringa +="<option value=\"add_gmember_"+data.userId+"\">"+data.userName+"</option>";   
                }
                $("#add-group-select").append(stringa);    
                $('#add-group-select').multiSelect('refresh');  
                $('#add-group-select').multiSelect({
                  afterSelect: function(values){
                    alert("Select value: "+values);
                  },
                  afterDeselect: function(values){
                    alert("Deselect value: "+values);
                  }
                });

        }
    });
});
```

the `string` is :

```
<option value="add_gmember_1">Ken</option>
<option value="add_gmember_2">wen</option>
<option value="add_gmember_3">win</option>
<option value="add_gmember_24">abc</option>
<option value="add_gmember_26">zoo</option>
<option value="add_gmember_28">1</option>
<option value="add_gmember_29">2</option>
<option value="add_gmember_30">3</option>
<option value="add_gmember_31">4</option>
<option value="add_gmember_32">5</option>
```

Comment: are you able to draw multiselect after dynamically adding options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get selected option value by simple jquery change function 
for E.g

```
$('#add-group-select').change(function(){

console.log($(this).val());  // this will give values of selected option by array

});
```

[JS BIN Example](http://jsbin.com/fugojofiwo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) It will return you an array of selected values